# всем привет! Никак не могу разобраться, почему после ввода пользователем значения new_el программа еще раз запрашивает ввод

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "functions.c"

int main()
{
    int new_el = 0;
    int setter;
    Sset *head_set = NULL;
    printf("1.Print a list.\n2.Add new element on the list.\n3.Remove element x.\n4.Print length.\n5.Exit.\n");

    while ((setter = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (setter) {
            case ('1'):
                print_set(head_set);
                break;
            case ('2'):
                printf("Please, set new element: ");
                scanf("%d ", &new_el);
                add_new_element(head_set, new_el);
                printf("Done!\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что `getchar` не равен EOF... EOF это терминатор STDIN.  В Windows он вызывается на F6, в *nix на CTRL+D....

Comment: может быть вы не понимаете, что `break;` выходит только из `switch`. А цикл `while` продолжается. Поможет простой `goto` для выхода из цикла. *Пусть меня простят религиозники "`goto` это анархия".*

Comment: можно просто сам switch в функцию запихнуть, тогда break превращается в return и все будет работать.

Comment: @AlexGlebe те, кто не любят `goto`, просто не умеют его готовить)))

Comment: те, кто не любит goto, просто не знают, откуда это у них. Они все цитируют одного автора (известно достаточно), но при этом не знают об этом.